# LRTHW exercise 20 strange output

Tags: ruby, powershell, output

For this exercise I wrote all the code perfectly and even double checked by literally copying and pasting the code from the book (Learn Ruby the Hard Way). For some reason when I call the `print_a_line()` function, it won't print out the `current_line` argument I pass through until the 3rd call where it will print out 3 before the line. Is there some flushing of the IO stream I am missing out on here or some nuance with Powershell?

I am running Ruby 2.0.0p576 (x64) on Windows 8 64 bit machine.

Code:

```
input_file = ARGV.first

def print_all(f)
  puts f.read
end

def rewind(f)
  f.seek(0)
end

def print_a_line(line_count, f)
  puts "#{line_count}, #{f.gets.chomp}"
end

current_file = open(input_file)

puts "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

puts "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Comment: What does your output look like?

Comment: It has everything right except for printing out the line numbers. EX:
 `, This is line 1.`
 `, This is line 2.`
 `3, This is line 3.`

Comment: That works for me, so I'm not sure what you're seeing or why that's malfunctioning. Are you running exactly this code? Are you running it with `ruby` or `irb`?

Comment: I am running exactly that code and I am running it with ruby from an external .rb file. I could take a screenshot of my output?

Comment: Screenshots are completely unnecessary for plain text. This code, as-is, worked just fine, so I'm curious what could be wrong. Do you have any other place or way you could run this?

Comment: You know what, I somehow fixed it. I deleted the test.txt file and remade it and now it works perfect. There may have been some underlying formatting from me re-using that file with many different tests.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the test.txt file and recreated it from scratch and this made the code work perfectly. I am not 100% as to why, but I have a hunch that from reusing that file in many different tests and playing around in Powershell I had inadvertently left some strange formatting in the file causing it to behave differently.

Comment: It's possible that there was some crazy stuff in there that, when output, would cause the terminal to paint over itself.